# Arduino serial hex decimal values code

Tags: serial, uart

I'm trying to send heximal values from arduino to PZEM-04 power module (it shows voltage, current and ect.) over serial communication in heximal format and get values in decimal format for further actions with them. Any help with the code please? 
One of the commands: 
Send command: B4 C0 A8 01 01 00 1E
Reply data: A4 00 00 00 00 00 A4

Edit: I am connecting wires from PZEM module TTL to arduino "serial port": TX-RX, RX-TX, VCC-VCC, GND-GND, so it's serial communication.. 
    PZEM module: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/PEACEFAIR-AC-100A-Electric-power-monitoring-and-communication-module-power-meter-power-energy-Volt-Ammeter/1773456_32373508101.html

Comment: Please add link to communication format/protocol.

Comment: I just added more information.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: That for the extra info. I read this differently. You should send binary data with the hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 2):

A possible implementation of the protocol using serial read/write of binary data (command and response).

```
void send(Stream& ios, uint8_t cmd[6])
{
  uint8_t sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    uint8_t c = cmd[i];
    sum += c;
    ios.print((char) c);
  }
  ios.print((char) sum);
}

bool recv(Stream& ios, uint8_t res[6])
{
  uint8_t sum = 0;
  uint8_t c;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    while (!ios.available());
    c = ios.read();
    sum += c;
    res[i] = c;
  }
  while (!ios.available());
  c = ios.read();
  return (sum == c);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while (!Serial);

  uint8_t cmd[] = { 0xB4, 0xC0, 0xA8, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00 };
  uint8_t res[6];
  send(Serial, cmd);
  recv(Serial, res);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much Mikael Patel, you cleared it a lot to me. Now it's only needed to analize code, and insert other commands. After that I'm going to connect bluetooth module and send values to smartphone somehow, haha. Thanks again!